# Discord direct message limit rate

Tags: discord

I just used discord API (discord.js) to send 45 direct messages to 45 users. Then I got this message from my developer panel:

**Bot Quarantined**

*Your bot has been flagged by our anti-spam system for abusive behavior. While your bot is quarantined, it is unable to join any more guilds, or send any direct messages to users it has not messaged before. If you believe this to be in error, click here and select "Appeal an Action Trust and Safety took on my bot" as the Report Type to submit an appeal.*

How can I fix this issue and make my bot normal again? And I want to know how to queue my direct messages for not getting ban by discord. something like 2 messages per minute or ...? Thanks

Comment: Hi, I know it is an old question, but did you solve the issue and how? Have currently the same problem.

Comment: @Chris2011931 no sadly, I contacted discord and didn't receive anything from them. I just removed the application and created a new one if you can do so.

Comment: Ok, I will do so. How did you solve it that the Bot was not banned again? In my case, I have to send approximately 110 direct messages to different people. What delay did you use or did you something else to avoid the bot being quarantined?

Comment: @Chris2011931 I don't know the rate limit to send direct messages, but try to send messages with different content and not that fast, and you will be just fine.

Comment: I just tried it again with a new created bot. I added a delay of 10 seconds after sending the messages. Furthermore, i added different text. The bot was again quarantined. Can you please provide me with your values for timing? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: @Chris2011931 I sent one direct message every 5 minutes for +1000 users, and everything was fine. I created an array containing ten different messages to send in order.